# FIFO queue in Java

Tags: java

I am having a hard time understanding how to use the methods from the LucasQueue interface.

NOTE: This is not me asking you to write my homework. I am simply asking the community for guidance.

> Complete the given FloatingQueue class. You
> must implement the following operations specified in the given LucasQueue
> interface. This is a subset of the operations specified in the Queue interface in the
> Java API, which is part of the Java Collections Framework.

```
public class FloatingQueue<T>
{
 private T[] theData; /**The underlying data array*/

 public FloatingQueue() {

 theData = (T[]) new Object[ 10 ];
 }
}
```

```
public interface LucasQueue<E> {
    
    /**Insert the newData at the end of the Queue 
     * @return true if-and-only-if the Queue has changed due to this operation 
     */
    public abstract boolean offer ( E newData );  
    
    /**Remove and return the item at the front of the Queue 
     * @return front of queue, or null if the Queue is empty
     */
    public abstract E poll();   
    
    /**Return the item at the front of the Queue 
     * @return front of queue, or null if the Queue is empty
     */
    public abstract E peek();   
    
    /**Return the number of items currently in the Queue*/
    public abstract int size();  
    
    /**@return true if-and-only-if the queue is empty*/
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();  
    
    /**Empty the Queue.  The size of the queue is 0 after this operation */
    public abstract void clear(); 
    
    /**@return a String represents the current contents of the Queue */
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

Below is the Tester code

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println( "Hello world" );
        
        String s = "";
        boolean flag = false;
        
        FloatingQueue<String> foo = new FloatingQueue<String>();  

        if ( ! foo.isEmpty() )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 1" );
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[]") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 2" );
        
        flag = foo.offer( "alice" );  
        if ( !flag )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 3");
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[alice]") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 4");
        
        foo.offer( "bob" );    
        foo.offer( "chad" );   
        foo.offer( "dan" );   
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[alice,bob,chad,dan]") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 5");
        
        s = (String) foo.poll();
        if ( ! s.equals("alice") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 6");
        
        s = (String) foo.poll();
        if ( ! s.equals("bob") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 7");     
        
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[chad,dan]") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 8");
        
        foo.offer("ed");
        foo.offer("fran");
        s = (String) foo.poll();
        if ( ! s.equals("chad") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 9");
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[dan,ed,fran]") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 10");

        foo.offer("gian");
        foo.offer("hal");
        foo.offer("ian");
        foo.offer("joe");
        foo.offer("ken");
        foo.offer("lara");
        foo.offer("maria");
        foo.offer("ned");
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[dan,ed,fran,gian,hal,ian,joe,ken,lara,maria,ned]") )  
            throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 11");
        
        foo.clear();
        if ( foo.size() != 0 )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 12");
        if ( ! foo.isEmpty() )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 13" );
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[]") )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 14");

        foo.offer("gian");
        foo.offer("hal");
        foo.offer("ian");
        foo.offer("joe");
        foo.offer("ken");
        foo.offer("lara");
        foo.offer("maria");
        foo.offer("ned");
        
        if ( foo.size() != 8 )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 15");
        if ( foo.isEmpty() )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 16" );
        if ( ! foo.toString().equals("[gian,hal,ian,joe,ken,lara,maria,ned]") )  
            throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 17");
        
        foo.clear();
        s = (String) foo.poll();
        if ( s != null )  throw new RuntimeException ("Fails test case 18");
        
        System.out.println( "Good-bye" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow.  This looks like a homework assignment, correct?  Well it's not going to help you much if I just solve it for you!  Maybe you could try working your way through it, show your work, and someone can help you with the next step?  As it is, you're simply saying "I dont understand any of this" which makes me wonder if you skipped class....

Comment: @Joe Coder
I agree, I guess I needed to make it more clear that I was only seeking guidance as I am a little rusty on the topic. 
user16320675:
Thanks for that, I am having a hard time understanding the material is all, but after working some of it out it's making more sense.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand a few basics:

- How to compile the code you have in your question (you should get an error on line 14 of `Tester` saying `Cannot resolve method 'isEmpty'`. That's expected at this point).
- What a method is and how to add one to your `FloatingQueue` class.
- How to run your code in debug mode, setting breakpoints, and stepping line by line or into function calls.

If there are any of those things you don't know how to do, talk to your teacher or classmates and learn how.

The methods on `LucasQueue` are the methods you need to add to `FloatingQueue`. If you change the declaration of `FloatingQueue` to:

```
public class FloatingQueue<T> implements LucasQueue<T> {
   ...
```

then the compiler will help you get that right.

Once you have added a method with the same name, parameters and return type as each of those methods, `Tester` will compile, and will try to use your `FloatingQueue` class. If the methods are correctly implemented, the tests will pass, otherwise it will throw an exception.